# How to sum up multiple columns records and select distinctly at the same time in one fell swoop?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table that holds these items

```
Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 | Column_4
------------------------------------------
John1        1         1            2        
John1        3         2            2    
John1        2         3            2    
Eric         4         2            2
Eric         4         7            2    
Christina    1         2            2
Christina    1         2            3
```

I want to do a couple things:

1) I want to get all of the records in **Column_1**, but I don't want to repeat names. For example, I know I can do a `SELECT DISTINCT Column_1 FROM MyTable` which will achieve this. In return I will get: **John1, Eric, Christina**

2) I want to also add up the totals of each column which I know I can do by `SELECT SUM(Column_2) FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTable where Column_1 = John1 ) AS p1` which will acheive this. In return I will get: **6**

3) I want to also do the same for **Column_3** and **Column_4** where **Column_1** is equal to a certain criteria like above.

> > The **Problem**: How can I achieve all three of these queries in **one query** is that even possible?

My Final Result should look like this:

```
John1      6    6    6
Eric       8    9    4
Christina  2    4    5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using `group by Column1` and `sum()` the columns you want to aggregate.

```
select 
    Column_1
  , sum(Column_2) as sumColumn_2
  , sum(Column_3) as sumColumn_3
  , sum(Column_4) as sumColumn_4
from t
group by Column_1
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XACANR1610

returns:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Column_1  | sumColumn_2 | sumColumn_3 | sumColumn_4 |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Christina |           2 |           4 |           5 |
| Eric      |           8 |           9 |           4 |
| John1     |           6 |           6 |           6 |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver.